# CCNet Dashboard empty

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Until yesterday everything went fine and I could see all my three projects at the dash board (localhost:port/ViewFarmReport.aspx). I've only edited the dashboard.config (also set it to defautl again) but nothing changed and I still cannot see any of my projects. Does anyone know what to do?
I only get to see the "normal" dashboard surface but without any projects in it.

Answer (score 2):

works again :)
reboot is alsways good...

Comment: Same holds for me. The projects were building, but dashboard didn't show any projects. Just restarting CIS service didn't help, but reboot fixed the problem. Thanks for the (obvious-for-windows) hint!

Answer (score 0):

Modification in the file "dashboard.config" needs that you :

- Restart web server
- Purge cache on your client web browser
- Pray 10 times ... because as you discovered, sometimes you need to reboot the machine :(

Comment: normally it's enough, to kill the IIS and the CruiseControl Process :)